# Netbeans configuration problem

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans6.8

I am using Netbeans 6.8

The problem is that the projects explorer (that displays all the projects and their contents) displays each package as a node. For instance, if there is package hierarchy like this;

- com.mycompany.myproject.package1.package1.1

then it displays 5 nodes for the five packages which is very disturbing while development.

Is there any way by which I can configure it(Netbeans) so that it groups all the subpackages of a package under one node and displays the subpackages only when I expand the package node?

Comment: I don't do Netbeans, but in Eclipse you can configure view filters in *Customize View* menu and there's an option *Empty packages* which is by default turned on (and thus get hidden by default). See if similar "view filter" option exist in Netbeans.

Comment: You might want to add a screen shot of what you see now plus a text-based 'screen shot' of what you would like to see.  That will help clarify your question a bit.

Comment: One additional bit of info that might be useful... If you open the 'com.mycompany.myproject' node, what do you see as the content of the node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Projects window, display the context menu without selecting a project, and go "View Java Packages as > List".

You can toggle between List or Tree view with that option.